# upgrading asp.net mvc apps

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Upgrading MVC apps done with VS 2010 has been the biggest issue for me. I have an application that I use to run various websites and I maintain and develop this application separetely then upgrade the sites based on it. A lot of things might change during development of a new version - new Views, new Controllers, stuff added into JS files, updated stylesheets etc.

I've searched around the web but nothing useful came up besides this [Haack's article](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/15/building-a-self-updating-site-using-nuget.aspx) but no source code is available.

I also tried making a Nuget package for the entire MVC app and while this works, it doesn't package up the resource files (an issue within Nuget itself) and my apps rely on those so until this is fixed I cannot use this method.

I checked how others do it and [this](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/install-and-setup/upgrading-an-umbraco-installation) pretty much summarizes Umbraco's way and it's the same painful way of a dozen of steps like I do it now.

Do you have any good advice on it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the target OS, but I create native packages, i.e. .deb for Ubuntu servers.

However this still means you need to specify all files, manage configuration, upgrade database schemes. But if you test this on a CI server it becomes more reliable, and you can do it iteratively. This is all part of good deployment practice. I can recommend the [Continuous Delivery](http://goo.gl/V9dqc) book.